# Outputting matrix with softmax activation on each row in TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, one-hot-encoding, softmax

I am constructing a TensorFlow (2.0) model which takes an image (30x100 matrix) as input and wish to be able to have outputs (and labels) of the form

```
[
  [0.0, 0.3, 0.7, 0.0],
  [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  [0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2]
]
```

i.e each row has a separate softmax activation meaning they sum to one. In the training data only one of the elements in each row is 1 and the rest are 0, I believe this is known as a one-hot encoding. Therefore my question would be; how do I configure the last layer (and loss function) to have a one-hot encoding on my labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be a variant of multi label classification. For ease we can concatenate the outputs of the 3 softmax layers and use binary crossentropy loss. For predictions we can reshape the concatenated outputs.

#### Working Code

```
inputs = Input(shape=(2,))
output = Dense(4, activation='relu')(inputs)

output_1 = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(output)
output_2 = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(output)
output_3 = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(output)

# concatenate the outputs
output = concatenate([output_1, output_2, output_3], axis=1)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam') 

# Two training examples each of 2 features
x = np.array([[1,2],
              [2,1]])

# Output labels
y = np.array([[[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0]],
              [[0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]]])

# Fatten the y per sample to match the model output shape
model.fit(x, y.reshape(len(x), -1))

# Predications
y_hat = model.predict(x)
y_hat = y_hat.reshape(len(x),-1,4)

print (y_hat)
```

Output:

```
array([[[0.0418521 , 0.63207364, 0.06171123, 0.26436302],
        [0.54364955, 0.19503883, 0.09884372, 0.16246797],
        [0.06045745, 0.09223039, 0.7325132 , 0.11479893]],

       [[0.05648099, 0.40420422, 0.12369599, 0.41561884],
        [0.64175993, 0.14215547, 0.07769462, 0.13838997],
        [0.07918497, 0.1764104 , 0.57678604, 0.1676186 ]]], dtype=float32)
```

Also you can verify that each row sums up to 1 by using `y_hat.sum(axis=2)`

Answer (score 2):

provided that rows are independent one from each other, seems to me that your case can be a multi output case. You can have 3 outputs with 5 values each.

```
input1 = Input(shape = (input_shape))
# some layers
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(input1)
# .....

outputs1 = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name="row1")(x)
outputs2 = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name="row2")(x)
outputs3 = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name="row3")(x)
model = Model(input1, [outputs1, outputs2, outputs3])
```